# Forcing docker option for container in Kubernetes

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

Is it possible to make sure that my containers are running with a specific docker option.

I need to run my container with the `--device` option. I cannot use device plugin because I am running a Windows container and device manager does not seem to implemented for Windows.

Comment: Can you guarantee the device will be available on every node in the cluster?  Are you running this in a DaemonSet, or can you otherwise tolerate the pod potentially getting moved around?

Comment: @David MazeI  I can guarantee that the device will be available on every node. For now I havn't decided what kind of workload but it is very likely to be a daemonset

Comment: Is it helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290752/how-to-use-device-dev-video0-with-kubernetes

Comment: @KoopaKiller unfortunately it does not because my device cannot be mapped to a volume. Unfortunately host type volume  should exist on disk for the pods to be valid